# Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED when I try to run npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, build, npx

I'm working on an android app on react-native using vscode and a physical android device and it keeps showing the error below while trying to build using npx react-native run-android.

```
Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
38 actionable tasks: 38 executed
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s

    at makeError (/home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

This keeps happening usually when I start off a new project and usually have to start a new project altogether for this error to resolve.

**These are few of the things I tried to resolve the error.**

1. Tried ./gradlew clean and tried building app again.
2. Enabled multiDexEnabled in app/build.gradle
3. I'm using a physical android device to run the app. I tried uninstalling the app and tried to build the app again.
4. Removed node_modules, cleared npm cache and tried installing all node_modules again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Below are few details about the project**

**package.json dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^13.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^13.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^13.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^3.2.6",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
```

**android/build.gradle info**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**Output of ./gradlew build --warning-mode all**

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 29.0.2
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.0.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 13.1.1 (13,1,1 - 13001001)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 29.0.2
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 13.1.1 (13,1,1 - 13001001)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_firestore
:react-native-firebase_firestore package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_firestore:firebase.bom using default value: 29.0.2
:react-native-firebase_firestore package.json found at /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/package.json
:react-native-firebase_firestore:version set from package.json: 13.1.1 (13,1,1 - 13001001)
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_firestore:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/akaranath/Desktop/krop_delivery_cs/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-screens
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[]) for more details.
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the now obsolete `jcenter()` repository with `mavenCentral()`.

In case of missing packages, not still could provide them with `mavenLocal()` or a `flatDir` repo.

The output has a more suspicious lines, which hint for a insane build environment.

Comment: I tried replacing it in build.gradle but it doesn't seem to work. It shows the same Task :app:packageDebug FAILED.

Comment: When I try deleting the build files, .gradle folders and try a gradle clean and rebuild it shows a Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I change *android\build.gradle*

```
...
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral() //jcenter()
    }
...
allprojects {

    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.facebook.yoga", "proguard-annotations")
                includeModule("com.facebook.fbjni", "fbjni-java-only")
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
```

I change *android\gradle.properties*

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0
```